# HTML5 multiple <figcaption> inside <figure>

Tags: html

I would like to know if a `figure` element can contain more than one `figcaption` child?

I read something somewhere (sorry, now I can't find it) that seemed to suggest it couldn't- yet I am sure that a `figure` can contain more than one `img`, so that seems illogical.

What if I have two related images side by side, for which I want separate captions?

Comment: Searching your title on google came up with this: "Only one <figcaption> element may be nested within a <figure>, although the <figure> element itself may contain multiple other child elements"

Comment: Figure can be nested, so you can wrap each img in a figure with a figcaption and still have a figure element surrounding the whole lot.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks, Alochi- this is what I was looking for! If you want to add your comment as an answer, I'll accept.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can nest the `img` plus its `figcaption` into multiple figure tags. To add more semantics to the code you can add an ARIA `role` attribute.

```
<figure role="group">
    <figcaption>Caption for the whole group of images</figcaption>

    <figure>
        <img src="picture1.jpg" alt="Description of picture 1">
        <figcaption>Caption for Picture 1</figcaption>
    </figure>

    <figure>
        <img src="picture2.jpg" alt="Description of picture 2">
        <figcaption>Caption for Picture 2</figcaption>
    </figure>

</figure>
```

Comment: Figures cannot be contained within figcaptions.

Comment: "within figcaptions"? I don't see a figure within a figcaption in the code… Everything seems valid to me.

Comment: I know, but I can't undo it. :( If it's any consolation, it dinged me too.

Answer (score 4):

In HTML5 **figure** is a *sectioning root.* It may have *sectioning root* or *flow content* as content. A **figcaption** is *flow content,* and may only have *flow content* as content. So, a **figcaption** may not have a **figure** as content.

A **figure** may have another **figure** as content, however. Keep in mind that a **figcaption** must be the *first* or *last child* of a **figure.**

So code might look like this:

```
<figure>
  <img>
  <figure>
    <figcaption></figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figcaption></figcaption>
</figure>
```

or

```
<figure>
  <figcaption></figcaption>
  <img>
  <figure>
    <figcaption></figcaption>
  </figure>
</figure>
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figure
and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figure

Comment: HTML5.1 is looking to change this, so that a figcaption can be anywhere inside a figure.

Answer (score -1):

For what I can see, you can only use it once within figure: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_figcaption.asp

Comment: use of w3schools as an authority should be discouraged. It is imprecise and not well regarded.